# How can I select a chess piece and move it in this chess game?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I seem to have become stuck when trying vigorously to code a simple chess game for a grade in my class.

This is my code so far. PS: Some variables and functions are in Norwegian.

What I was trying to achieve was this:

When you click on a piece the possible moves light up. This might be possible by eliminating and differentiating what pieces are selected, then that piece could be moved to the square with that background color.

```js
var board = [
  ["bRook", "bKnight", "bBishop", "bQueen", "bKing", "bBishop", "bKnight", "bRook"],
  ["bPawn", "bPawn", "bPawn", "bPawn", "bPawn", "bPawn", "bPawn", "bPawn"],

  ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
  ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
  ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
  ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],

  ["wPawn", "wPawn", "wPawn", "wPawn", "wPawn", "wPawn", "wPawn", "wPawn"],
  ["wRook", "wKnight", "wBishop", "wQueen", "wKing", "wBishop", "wKnight", "wRook"],
];

var ut = document.getElementById("sjakkBrett");

function createBoard() {
  for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    var row = document.createElement("div");
    row.className = "rekke";

    for (let j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
      var boks = document.createElement("div")
      row.appendChild(boks);
      boks.id = `${j} : ${i}`;

      boks.addEventListener("click", clicked);

      if ((j % 2 == 0 && i % 2 == 0) || j % 2 == 1 && i % 2 == 1) {
        boks.style.backgroundColor = "white";
      }
      
      boks.className = "rute";
    }
    ut.appendChild(row);
  }

}

function brikkePlassering(x, y) {
  return document.getElementById(`${x} : ${y}`);
}

function updateBoard() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      //laster inn bilder på hver av rutene ved hjelp av board array.
      if (board[j][i]) {
        brikkePlassering(i, j).style.backgroundImage = `url('sjakk/${board[j][i]}.png')`
      } else {
        brikkePlassering(i, j).style.backgroundImage = "";
      }
    }
  }
}

function clicked(element) {
  element = element.srcElement;

  let brettVerdi = board[e.id[4]][e.id[0]][0];
  let posisjon = [parseInt(e.id[0]), parseInt(e.id[4])];

  let trykketBakgrunn = e.style.backgroundColor;
}

createBoard();
updateBoard();
```

```css
.rute {
  background-color: rgb(6, 102, 6);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-size: cover;
}

.rekke {
  width: 800px;
  display: flex;
}

#sjakkBrett {
  border: solid;
  width: 800px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Sjakk ♞</h1>
  <div id="sjakkBrett">

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: check your code, the snippet gives error in javascript file

Comment: you would need to create a list of all posible moves for said piece, then overlay a grid which has the background color.

Comment: The errors occur from the missing images folder. The folder is named sjakk (=chess in Norwegian). The array has the names of the images. I.e bPawn's image is named "bPawn.png"